# Capture visible portion of UIScrollView and subview

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, uiscrollview

I have zoomable image in a `UIScrollview`. Once the image is scrolled to the user's liking, the scrollview is locked. A `UITextField` can then be edited, and is (currently) added to the `UIImageView`. The context of the image is captured and saved.

Without scrolling, this works fine, however, the context is based on the frame of the `UIImageView`. How can it capture the visible portion of the screen instead, leaving out the navigation bar and toolbar? The function used to save the image is below.

```
    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
      let newImage = imageStore.createImage(textLabelBottom.text, imageName: "image1") { () -> UIImage in

        // Can't add the textLabel to imageView because its size changes
        self.imageView.addSubview(self.textLabelBottom)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        self.imageView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
        self.imageToSave = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return self.imageToSave
    }
    imageStore.saveImage(newImage)
    self.showActivityViewController()
}
```

I wan't to save the visible portion of the image based on its position in the scrollview with the `textLabel` in a static spot. The code currently adds `textLabel` to the same point in the image regardless of zoom, with the saved image either very small or very large based on the `UIScrollView`.

**Update:** I changed the code to the following:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
      let newImage = imageStore.createImage(textLabelBottom.text, imageName: "image1") { () -> UIImage in

        // Can't add the textLabel to imageView because its size changes
        self.imageView.addSubview(self.textLabelBottom)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageScrollView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let offset: CGPoint = self.imageScrollView.contentOffset
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y)
        self.imageScrollView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
        self.imageToSave = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return self.imageToSave
    }
    imageStore.saveImage(newImage)
    self.showActivityViewController()
}
```

This works properly, but the text field is obviously out of place. Do I add it to a specific `CGPoint` within the context?

**Update 2:**

It's my understanding that `CGContextTranslateCTM` changes the coordinate system to that of the layer you're working on. In this case, the new `{0, 0}` would be at the offset of the scrollview. When I want to place my textfield into the context, though, it doesn't show up in the right place (offscreen). Trying something like this:

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
          let newImage = imageStore.createImage(textLabelBottom.text, imageName: "image1") { () -> UIImage in

```
        // Can't add the textLabel to imageView because its size changes
        self.imageView.addSubview(self.textLabelBottom)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageScrollView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let offset: CGPoint = self.imageScrollView.contentOffset
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y)
        self.imageScrollView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
        //Move to the correct point and render
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, /*point1*/, /*point2*/)
        self.textLabelBottom.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
        self.imageToSave = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return self.imageToSave
    }
    imageStore.saveImage(newImage)
    self.showActivityViewController()
}
```

What else do I need to do to the context to do this properly?

Comment: Render the scroll view instead of the image view.

Comment: Done. And it works. Would I simply add `textField` to a specific `CGPoint` instead of a subview?

Comment: I do not know where you want the text field to go or how you want it to behave.

Comment: Sorry. `textField` should be a caption at the bottom of the image. Adding it as a subview of the `UIImageView` would put it offscreen when the image is repositioned in the `UIScrollView`. I want it at a fixed point of at the bottom of the saved image/context. Adding         `self.textLabelBottom.layer.renderInContext(ctx)
` above `self.imageScrollView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)` isn't right.

Comment: "I want it at a fixed point" Sure, then just draw it at that point. But if it is a caption, you don't want a text field; you just want _text_. Am I understanding correctly? So just use the string `drawAtPoint:` method as part of your image creation.

Comment: It's a user editable UITextField shown in front of the scrollable image. When the image is placed, the text field becomes editable. When editing is finished, both layers should be saved in the context. I'm guessing the solution requires me to move the context to the correct point, then `textFieldBottom.layer.renderInContext(ctx)`.